# Filter pandas columns based on row condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

i have the following dataframe called df.

```
        x1    x2   x3 ....
row1    12   3.4    5  ...
row2     1     3    4 ...
row3  True False True ...
...
```

I want to display the columns where all the row3 values are True.

so like columns `x1` and `x3` will be displayed in this example.

I know how to do it the other way when i want to filter rows based on column info but im not sure how to do it when i want to filter based on a row.

I tried

```
df.loc[:,df.iloc['row3']==True]
```

but i get an error.

How do i do this? any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iloc` asks you to pass (list of) integers. Try `loc`:

```
df.loc[:,df.loc['row3']]
```

Comment: what about the part where i only want to return a certain column? the true values

Comment: Since your `row3` already boolean, the above code would show only columns `x1,x3` as expected. `==True` is redundant.

Comment: oh... it works. can u explain why though? i dont see any conditions, what if i wanted the columns that were false?

Comment: wait nevermind i got it, my mistake was using iloc instead of loc. it works totally fine now i didnt read your first statement. thanks a lot

Comment: @anarchy the row itself is condition. For `False` values, use either `~df.loc['row3']` or `df.loc['row3']==False`. They are a little different when `NaN` value presents in the row.

Comment: what if i wanted to add one more condition? is it possible?, lets say i wanted the row2 values that were greater than 3