# Filter pandas columns based on multiple row condition

Tags: python, pandas, filter

This is an extension to my earlier question.

[Filter pandas columns based on row condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66357241/filter-pandas-columns-based-on-row-condition)

Now i want to have multiple conditions to filter columns.

Here is my data

```
        x1    x2   x3 ....
row1    12   3.4    5  ...
row2     1     3    4 ...
row3  True False True ...
...
```

`df.loc[[:,df.loc['row3']==True]` works if I just want to filter the `row3` condition of `True`

I want to filter the columns where `row3` is `true`,

`and` i want to filter the columns where `row2` is `>3`

So in this example only column x3 should appear.

I tried the following code but I get an error. I also tried adding brackets.

```
df.loc[:,df.loc['row3']==True & :,df.loc['row2']>3]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
x = (pd.to_numeric(df.loc['row2'],'coerce').gt(3)) & (df.loc['row3']=='True')
```

---

**x:**

```
x1    False
x2    False
x3     True
dtype: bool
```

then you can easily apply filter to get the column where the value is true.

```
x[x].index[0]
```

---

output:

```
x3
```

---

```
df.loc[:,x]
```